# Typescript with PropTypes in React throws error with enums

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-proptypes

I'm having some issues with defining the PropTypes for a string enumerator. I have the following type in Typescript:

```
state: "pending"|"accepted"|"rejected",
```

and the corresponding propType:

```
state: PropTypes.oneOf(["pending","accepted","rejected"]).isRequired,
```

This, however throws the following error: "Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"pending" | "accepted" | "rejected"'.ts(2322)". I really don't know what to do! Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Comment: What line throws that error, exactly?

Comment: The second line, the PropType one. It detects as "string" the propType, and as "pending" | "accepted" | "rejected" the TypeScript property

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reducible example? The closest I got was https://tsplay.dev/w11AYw. But I'm not familiar enough with this library to get it wired up how you have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is
`state` has `type` `"pending"|"accepted"|"rejected"` and its not Enum its Union type and`["pending","accepted","rejected"]` has `type` `string[]`

you have to Tell Typescript its `"pending"|"accepted"|"rejected" []` not `string[]`

For convenience I'm going to create a new type

```
type State = 'pending' | 'accepted' | 'rejected';

state: State = 'pending'

// we have to tell typescript its type is not string[] but State[] 
state: PropTypes.oneOf(['pending','accepted','rejected'] as State[]).isRequired
```

[here is Example that I have created for you.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-rejwaj)